# Can not communicate with HTTPS enabled services from localhost

Tags: vue.js, https, localhost

In My `VueJS` application, my `localhost` which runs on port 8080 can not communicate with HTTPS  enabled services.

In my `vue.config.js` file I kept `devServer : { https:true}` but with no luck, anyone how to overcome this situation?

Comment: Can you share what error you got? Please add some more details.

Comment: Did you checked if CORS is enabled in your server or tried using CORS extension for Chrome?